# How can show grid view with other view in single page #flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to add grid view and other view in same page?
I try with listview but it is showing error

> I/flutter (10293): Another exception was thrown:
>   'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed
>   assertion: line 461 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true. I/flutter
>   (10293): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter
>   'scrollOffsetCorrection' was called on null. I/flutter (10293):
>   Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method
>   'debugAssertIsValid' was called on null. I/flutter (10293): Another
>   exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'visible' was
>   called on null

```
  body:ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("checking"),
        Container(
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          childAspectRatio: .6,
          children: _list.map((p) => ProductManagment(p)).toList(),
        ),
      ) 
      ],
    )
```

Another attempt

```
  body:ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("checking"),
         GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          childAspectRatio: .6,
          children: _list.map((p) => ProductManagment(p)).toList(),
        ) 
      ],
    )
```

again error

> I/flutter (10293): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#f955c relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
>   I/flutter (10293): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#a9147 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
>   I/flutter (10293): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#4a4c9 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
>   I/flutter (10293): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 461 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
>   I/flutter (10293): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'scrollOffsetCorrection' was called on null.
>   I/flutter (10293): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'debugAssertIsValid' was called on null.
>   I/flutter (10293): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'visible' was called on null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should just set height of the `Container` or warp it by `Expanded` widget. And tell what happen?. Might be size is missing thats way error occurred.

**EDITED :**

```
 body:ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("checking"),
        Container(
        height: 300.0
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          childAspectRatio: .6,
          children: _list.map((p) => ProductManagment(p)).toList(),
        ),
      ) 
      ],
    )
```

Set  height: 300.0 in container. *(You can set height/width as per your requirement or try with **Expanded** widget)*

Comment: i am new in flutter

Comment: how to make scroling view by  replacing listview

Comment: List view it self work as scrollview .. .dont need to change. Just look at  https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs

Comment: but in my case i have a banner view then i added grid view and now it only scrolling grid item and the banner view fixed on top and when we try to scroll banner view it is moving but what we need is when gride is moving banner view  also need to scrool

Comment: i am an android java developer in this case we use nextedscrooling view what is the equelent for flutter?